# Čech cohomology and refinement of good cover

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

In Bott-Tu's book *Differential forms in Algebraic Topology*. When they prove Proposition 10.6(p112) , which is

> Proposition 10.6. Let $\mathbb R$ be the constant presheaf on a manifold $M$. Then the
> Čech cohomology of $M$ with values in $\mathbb R$ is isomorphic to the de Rham
> cohomology.

They claimed

*it is easily seen that this isomorphism is
compatible with refinement of good covers*.

If $\mathfrak U$ is a good cover of $M$, $\mathfrak V$ is a refinement of $\mathfrak U$, We have known that $H^n(\mathfrak U,\mathbb R)$ is isomorphic to $H^n(\mathfrak V,\mathbb R)$ by $f$. They meant  if $\omega$ is a cocycle in $C^n(\mathfrak U,\mathbb R)$, $[\omega]\in H^n(\mathfrak U,\mathbb R)$, then $f[\omega]$ =  [$\tilde \omega $], where $\tilde \omega$ is the restriction of $\omega $ on $\mathfrak V$ (n intersection of  $\mathfrak V$).

I do not know how to show this, since the refinement of a good cover is quite complete, so that I can not understand what exactly f is.